Connecting find_contours at the edge of an Image
Trying to use this code:
https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html
Problem is if the object falls off the image, that it doesnt close the contour to the next nearest open contour. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage import measure


# Construct some test data
r = masks[1]['segmentation']
# Find contours at a constant value of 0.8
contours = measure.find_contours(r, 0.8)

# Display the image and plot all contours found
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(r, cmap=plt.cm.gray)

for contour in contours:
    ax.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)

ax.axis('image')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
plt.show()


https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/_images/sphx_glr_plot_contours_001.png  how to close the contours for the objects at the edge of the image?

you can [edit] your post.

As far as I understand you need to use padding, i.e.:
r = np.pad(masks[1]['segmentation'], 1)
